# How to enforce SQL Server policies in order to avoid users enabling bad practices

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have some rogue Windows Administrators who give themselves SA and then grant end-users SA.
These users then end up enabling auto-shrink, auto-growth percentage and all kinds of other poor practices - no matter how many times I tell them not to do it, they are still doing it.

Is there a way for me to use SQL Policies to forcefully stop these settings from being enabled? Currently I can only evaluate them and get a notification when the policies are failing.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail, how these Windows Administrators give themselves SA at SQL Servers ? Since you are on SQL Server 2016, being Domain Admin / Local (Windows) Administrator does not make them SA at SQL Server automatically, because there is no BuiltIn/Administrators group login at SQL Server since ~ 2008 as I recall.

Comment: Do these Windows Administrators install SQL Servers in question, and because of that they have passwords from "sa" account ?  or somebody provides them with "sa" password ? or somebody creates Windows authenticated login for them and adds it to "sysadmin" server role ?  or some other mechanism how they give themselves SA ?

Comment: @AlekseyVitsko Within our database environment, we authenticate as DBAs via a dedicated AD group. Any user within this group is given SA permission on the DB. Our Windows Admins are also Active Directory Admins, so they are simply adding themselves to this DBA group to gain permissions over the servers.

Comment: Then your problem is an organizational problem. You can get notified when these type of bad things happens, but not prevent them. This isn't for you to solve, you need to raise this with your managers.

Comment: You need to speak to the domain admin(s) to ensure they don't have rights to add themselves to the DBA group. If they *are* the domain admins, then you've got a business problem on your hands. Go to management and put in a complaint, get them to shape up or ship out (easier said than done, I know). One small workaround is to add a login trigger that prevents them logging on, they may still be able to remove this. You could also get alerts when certain settings or permissions are changed

Comment: To further the point about domain admins: I am DA where I work. Technically speaking I can do anything I want, up to and including impersonating another user, the system account or the DC server account. I could read/write anyone's data, log anyone's key-presses, frame someone with illegal data in their documents, delete the whole AD, take the company to ransom. I don't do any of these because I'm professional about it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to Policies in SQL Server here. Some types/level of policies, you cannot prevent. Technically, to "prevent" something using a policy in SQL Server means that the operation *is* performed, but the policy engine then does a rollback. Not all operations are rollback-able, hence the prevent functionality doesn't exist for all policy types.

So, in the end, you need to work out who has sysadmin privileges and make sure that only trusted persons has. In the end, this might have to go higher in the organization to get support.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you are using SQL Server 2016 you could set up a SQL Server Audit.

## SQL Server Management Studio

In SSMS you navigate down through the tree to `<SQL Server Instance> | Security | Audits`. Here you can right-click the **Audits** branch and start creating your Audit.

[image: SSSM | Instance | Security | Audits : New Audit]

You specify your options and click on OK.

[image: SSMS Server Audit]

Switch branches to `<SQL Server Instance> | Security | Server Audit Specifications` and right-click the branch to create new specs.

[image: SSMS | Instance | Security | Server Audit Specifications : New Server Audit Specifications ...]

Define which objects you  would like to audit and click on OK again.

[image: SSMS Server Audit Specifications]

Once you are done with the Audit and Specificaiton go back and right-click the **Audits** and the **Audit Specifications** to enable them:

[image: SSMS Enable Server Audit]

...

[image: SSMS Enable Server Audit Sprecifications]

## Test Audit a New User

Create a new pseudo-login and then look up the details via right-click **View Audit Logs** on the Audit branch:

[image: SSMS View Audit Logs]

lo and behold

[image: SSMS Audit Log]

You can then view who (the red arrows) created what (the entries marked in red).

## Answering your Question

> How to enforce SQL Server policies in order to avoid users enabling bad practices

Now while this doesn't enforce any policies, it sure does give you the ability to track down who is doing what on your SQL Server instances.

## Compliance and Security

Then you will have to take up the issue with your (IT) Compliance and/or Security Officer to determine what is allowed and what isn't allowed in the company according to the defined policies.

If no (compliance/security) policies exist, then you are going to have define some.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion SQL Policies would be just a "band aid" for your problem, it does not solve the root of the issue

You need to approach your manager and make him aware about the issue
Get green lights for restructuring / tightening security on SQL Servers you control

Sysadmins at SQL Servers can affect work of the applications, hurt business -> and get you fired

Check out this article for detailed information:

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/07/dba-training-plan-5-knowing-who-has-access/

Comment: I agree that it is a management issue. It has already been discussed internally and these individuals were removed from the DBA Active Directory group at the conclusion of the discussion. The problem is they have added themselves again and continue the same behaviour. You can imagine my frustration, so I began looking for a programatic way to solve the issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows Administrators already have access to an account in the **SysAdmin** server-level role, then that's the issue. You would need to disable all accounts (or change their passwords) that are in the **SysAdmin** role, and ensure only you knew the password to any active ones. As long as none of the remaining enabled **SysAdmin** Logins are an **Active Directory Group** then they should not be able to give themselves **SA** despite being Windows Administrators.

Note that despite the above is essentially the correct way to prevent them from giving themselves and others additional **SysAdmin** access, nothing is fool-proof, as demonstrated in this Microsoft article [Connect to SQL Server when system administrators are locked out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15) which details how to gain **SysAdmin** access to a SQL Server instance. The restriction there though is you need to be part of the **local Administrators group** of the machine that the SQL Server instance is on. If you're unable to ensure that the Windows Administrators don't have that access to the machine itself, then definitely don't share the above article with them. Knowledge is power.

Comment: Yes, it is, but have you ever seen a Windows Admin who is also an Active Directory Admin? I have - you can easily put yourself into Admin group should you want to give yourself access. While I would love to solve this issue from above, the company is too large, crosses too many borders with some cultures being rather 'indifferent' towards best practices and company policies. So, rather, I am looking for a solution that I can implement from the bottom up.

Comment: @Asher **AD Groups** become irrelevant when there is no **SysAdmin** role **SQL Logins** that are also an **AD Group**, as my answer states. I'm not sure of your own permissions, but if you have the ability to modify **SQL Logins**, you can disable any **SQL Logins** that are in the **SysAdmin** role, or remove that role from that **SQL Login**. At that point it's outside the control of the **Windows Admins / AD Admins** because **AD** becomes irrelevant in this context. Only workarounds like the second half of my answer is what's left as a possibility.